# Simpler way of solving Roles and Permission Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Query On Roles and Permission:

Admin ,Carer ,Care Manager ,All are the Fixed Roles .

Role "All"  conditions has a different functionality - it means to read /write should be given to everyone irrespective of  other roles.

For each role can have read or write permission.

I have solved this by creating a table called Permission with fields Permission Name, section , admin , C ,CM ,All and store data 1 if  "Read " and  2 if it is "Write" .

I tried with the intermediate table (HABTM) to connect role and permission .but the intermidiate table needs read and write option.

Tried with has_many :through functionality but the Role "All" functionality looks bit odd.

I would like to know is there any simpler way of achieving this ?**

Comment: Why not put the permissions in the roles model (as fields)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ton of time to writeup a great response (so I don't expect any credit) but I always use the [padlock_authorization](http://github.com/baldwindavid/padlock_authorization) gem to do roles on my rails sites and and love it.  It can degrade to handle a simple global role or complex model-based roles as well.

Other folks will have different libs they use; there a a good amount out there for Rails at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel ?  http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization

Answer (score 0):

I have had great experience with using [acl9](http://github.com/be9/acl9) in conjunction with [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic).
They work easily together, there also should be several example about using these two together.